# How to find files which contain specific string in directory using command "find"?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, find

This is my directory structure.

```
dirOut
├── dirIn1
│   ├── temp1
│   └── temp2
├── dirIn2
└── dirIn3
    ├── temp1
    ├── temp2
    ├── temp3
    └── temp4
```

dir is directory and temp is file.
I want to find files which contain specific string "Hello".
How do I use command "find" to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep), not a `find`, when you find files base on the content.

```
grep -lr Hello .
```

- -l : Normally grep print matching lines, with `-l` option, it just print the matched filenames.
- -r : recursively find files under the directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
find dirOut -type f -exec grep -l Hello {} +
```

The `-l` option tells `grep` to just list the filename if it finds a match, rather than showing all the matching lines.

You could also do it using the `-R` option to `grep` to search a directory recursively, rather than using `find`.

```
grep -R -l Hello dirOut
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name \* -exec grep -l "hello" {} \;
```

Execute this command while in dirOut.